# Regex for exactly phone number with any end

Tags: python, regex

I want to re.sub to change phone number format inside a string but stuck with the number detection.
I want to detect and change this format : ###-###-#### to this one: (###)-###-####
My regex :`(\d{3}\-)(\d{3}\-)(\d{4})$`
my sub: `(\1)-\2-\3`
I got stuck at that my regex can detect the number but if the number string ends like this: My number is 212-345-9999. It can not detect the number string end with any other character. When I change my regex to:`(\d{3}\-)(\d{3}\-)(\d{4})` it also changes the format of number like this: 123-456-78901 with is not a number I want to detect as a phone number.
Help me

Comment: This regex seems to work - `regex = r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}'`, can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Why are you passing things that aren't phone numbers into this regex?

Comment: Ex: "My phone number is 123-456-78901" with that regex and sub like this'(\1)-\2-\3 'the output will be "My phone number is (123)-456-78901"  which should be none since the format I want to detect is ###-###-#### not ###-###-#####

Comment: @Thien.Nguyen I updated my answer to include stricter matching. Could you check if it works as what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the word boundary `\b` to your regex pattern to require boundary characters such as space, period, etc. thus disallowing any additional numbers.

```
(\d{3}\-)(\d{3}\-)(\d{4})\b
```

But that will result to duplicate dashes. Instead, don't include the dash `-` in the captured groups so that they doesn't duplicate in the resulting string. So use this:

```
(\d{3})\-(\d{3})\-(\d{4})\b
```

If you want a stricter pattern to ensure that the string strictly contains the indicated pattern only and nothing more, match the start and end of string. Here, we will optionally catch an ending character `\W` that shouldn't be a digit nor letter.

```
^(\d{3})\-(\d{3})\-(\d{4})\W?$
```

- Just change `\W?` to `\W*` if you want to match arbitrary number of non-digit characters e.g. `123-456-7890.,`

**Sample Run:**

[image]

If you intend to only process the correctly-formatted numbers, then don't call `re.sub()` right away. First, check if there is a match via `re.match()`:

```
import re

number_re = re.compile(r"^(\d{3})\-(\d{3})\-(\d{4})\W?$")

for num in [
    "123-456-7890",
    "123-456-78901",
    "123-456-7890.",
    "123-456-7890.1",
]:
    print(num)
    if number_re.match(num):
        print("\t", number_re.sub(r"(\1)-\2-\3", num))
    else:
        print("\tIncorrect format")
```

Output:

```
123-456-7890
     (123)-456-7890
123-456-78901
    Incorrect format
123-456-7890.
     (123)-456-7890
123-456-7890.1
    Incorrect format
```

Comment: Hey, which tool are you using? talking about the image you posted... can you give the related link pls

Comment: oh.. nice. tysm